# Make the sidebar sub-menu active even after reloading page

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I want to make the sidebar active even after reloading a page.
For e.g In user sidebar there are 2 sub-menu of user. When I click on user sidebar menu it expands and show below 2 fields with active menu:

1. User name
2. User address

Like I selected user address option it is active now which is working properly. But I want to remain active even after reloading a page. For now, on reloading page, user sidebar will collapsed and not active. In data file, I have defined the menu as mentioned below:

```
{
    action: 'zmdi-widgets',
    title: 'message.widgets',
    items: [
        { title: 'message.username', path: '/widgets/user-name' },
        { title: 'message.useraddress', path: '/widgets/user-address' }
    ]
}
```

When above data contains an active field(boolean) which is true, sidebar menu shows active. I want to make an active field dynamically. On giving static value of active field it works fine even after reloading a page but on giving dynamically it does't work. Why Anyone knows? I am managing all this with vuex.